# Required Character Limit For Form Fields - DB, Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering what is the best limit of characters for each form fields.

As I am creating a database, I wonder if how many characters it should required.

Some of the common fields are the ff:

- first_name
- last_name
- email
- username
- password

Excited to your ideas guys. Please forgive me if I am asking a database related question here instead of programming. Let me know also if you know any more fields to add here. :)

Answer (score 0):

These fields will likely be stored as a string, which depending on the underlying database will be 255 characters (usually).

If you wish to limit the length, you can do it by adding a validation to the model. This way Rails will validate it and display an error on the page if it is too long. You can also set a minimum length

```
validates_length_of :first_name, maximum: 50
validates_length_of :first_name, minimum:  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different options to do so.

**Method 1:**

Add directly in DB:

`t.string :first_name, :limit => 12, :null => false`

If you already have the coulmn you can add a migration as.

`change_column :users, :first_name, :string, :limit => 24`

HEre is its definition:

**Limit:**

**limit**:  Sets the maximum size of the string/text/binary/integer fields.

**Method 2:**

As the other answer explained, you can add it in Model so that you can handle validations easily.

```
validates :first_name, length: { minimum: 10 }
validates :first_name, length: { maximum: 24 }
```